# Inconsistent voltage on buck converter (TPS54240)

Tags: circuit-design, buck, troubleshooting

I'm currently facing a weird issue. For one of my project I had to design a buck converter circuit in order to step down the voltage of three LiIon batteries to 3.3V so I can power a microcontroller.

I'm using the TPS54240 chip. The datasheet can be found [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54240.pdf?ts=1598810966071).
A typical application schematic is shown on page 31. Since said circuit outputs 3.3V I was able to more or less copy it. My schematic looks as follows:

[image]

After ordering a PCB prototype the buck converter didn't really work, unfortunately.
When I applied ~7.4V (2 LiIon batteries) to VCC the output showed ~3.3V as I was expecting. However once I connect a load, in my case the microcontroller, the voltage dropped to ~3.26V. Why is this happening? I thought a buck converter utilizes a feedback loop in order to maintain a constant voltage. The TPS54240 chip itself is rated for up to 2.5A in this case and my microcontroller isn't even pulling 100mA.

Even more confusing was the scenario when I connected ~11.1V (3 LiIon batteries) to VCC. In that case I measured ~2.6V at the output, which again dropped significantly to ~2.4V just when I connected a LED that drawed maybe 20mA. My microcontroller wasn't able to power on on such a low voltage making the circuit more or less useless.

Since I don't have a ton of experience with designing a circuit (this was my first project) I don't know how to troubleshoot this problem.
I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Edit: This is the PCB layout of the circuit.[image]

Edit 2: Here is a possibly fixed PCB layout.[image]

Comment: Something I just noticed: Is it possible that all of this is caused by the inductor not having an iron core? Apparently I chose one without one (according to the schematic symbol). Its a "Sunlord MWSA0603S-100MT" to be specific.

Comment: Link the data sheet of the inductor.

Comment: @Andyaka Here you go: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809291520_Sunlord-MWSA0603S-100MT_C132141.pdf Apparently it doesn't have an iron core.

Comment: if you didn't copy the recommended layout, can you post your board layout? load regulation that bad means your loop either isn't stable, or you're hitting some form of limit on the chip. On the board layout I'd basically just be looking for proximity of your comp network to the IC and any routing no-nos on your switch node.

Comment: Just did. You will have to "ignore" the other components though. I have a few more components on there for other purposes, which shouldn't interfere with the buck converter. I hope thats what you asked for.

Comment: Oh man, that layout looks [pants](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Thats%20pants). You just cannot treat buck converters as if you were wiring up an LED to a transistor. Where is your 0 volts?

Comment: I disabled the ground plane so you could actually see the actual traces. With that said, I'm sorry if the layout hurt your eyes. Could you tell me what exactly is so bad about it? Like do I have to have more spacing between components or place them closer to the IC ... and does that mean that the fact that the inductor is missing an iron core isn't the real problem?

Comment: You need to show the grounding but yes, from what I've seen your track thicknesses, component position and track interconnecting is poor. I doubt it's the inductor (now). Also show your output connector or at least indicate where your load connects. Typical example is the tortuous path taken to connect C17 and C18. Did you use an autorouter?

Comment: yeah... I'd start from scratch there. PCBs for high speed stuff like this are crucial. Check out page 42 in the datasheet for a recommended PCB layout. Key stuff is to keep you decoupling caps (ones between VCC and GND) very close to the IC, all of your COMP stuff must be close to the IC as well. Those long thin traces are essentially antennas and pick up all of the noise in your circuit, then amplify it and wreak havoc.

Comment: @Andyaka I kinda did, yes. Routing a PCB was surprisingly time consuming and actually wasn't that easy. So I used an autorouter and edited the traces afterwards to, for instance, remove 90° angles in traces. Afterall I was "just" building a prototype PCB. Anyways, thank you for taking your time to help me troubleshoot my problem. I'll research a little bit more about PCB layout design considerations and create a new PCB layout, which hopefully will fix my problems.

Comment: @Stiddily Yes, I didn't really consider this to be a problem. I will start from scratch with that in mind. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Gereon99 Agreed with the rest of people, why not getting the layout reviewed by peers before "wasting" a round of PCBs?

Comment: @eeintech I just didn't really think that the layout matters that much. (Afterall this was the first time I ever really designed a schematic + layout) After I got my schematic reviewed I thought that I can proceed with creating the PCB layout. I will most definitely get the next one reviewed before I place an order. At least I can learn from this mistake and hopefully not repeat it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you use an autorouter?

> *@Andyaka I kinda did, yes. Routing a PCB was surprisingly time
> consuming and actually wasn't that easy. So I used an autorouter and
> edited the traces afterwards to, for instance, remove 90° angles in
> traces.*

The routing, component placement and track widths are pretty bad in very important areas. Don't use an autorouter unless it's a last resort like for a backplane etc. where there are many repeated steps in the process.

### Problems

[image]

1. In light blue is the tortuous path taken from the inductor around the PCB to connect to C17 and C18 (the main bulk capacitors).
2. In purple is the far-too-long track from the switcher output to the flyback diode and inductor
3. The track widths are far too thin in my opinion and their length makes a big loop that could emit nasty interference to any close-by sensitive circuits.

- D5 should be right up close to the switcher and should ground directly to C17-C19 forming an island. That island should only connect to the rest of the design (not the power supply) at one unambiguous point to avoid switching currents creeping into ground areas of sensitive circuits.

### Recommendations

- L1 should be alongside D5
- C17 and C18 should be butted up to the above
- Then C19 and C20
- The ground connection of R31 (not visible in the layout) should make a connection directly to the island of ground for D5, C17, C18, C19 and C20
- Any other ground points associated with the switcher should be teed off from that ground island.

### Regarding the inductor

I see nothing in the data sheet that rules it out but, whenever I design a switcher, I pick an inductor that has a specified self-resonant-frequency (SRF) just to ensure that it is fit for purpose; in other words, if your switching frequency is (say) 200 kHz, I would want to pick an inductor that has an SRF of at least 1 MHz. Unfortunately I didn't see this stated in the data sheet nor can I say that the supplier has a decent quality system and decent tolerances. This last bit is about being careful who you choose. For instance, if one of the major recognized electronic component vendors was offering it in their catalogue I would be assured that the original manufacturer was OK.

Something like this: -

[image]

Comment: The auto-router is not the first issue, the placement is... Good answer though!

Comment: Wow, what a good answer! Theres still a lot to learn I suppose... thanks for taking your time to help me. Also, you said that R31 isn't visible on the layout, however it is right below the IC.

Comment: @Gereon99 The ground connection of R31 is not visible!!

Comment: Oh, sorry! Next time I will not make the ground plane invisible.

Comment: Andy, excellent answer. I would also recommend keeping R29 and C16 physically close to pin 8. You also want these two components kept away from your switching stuff, inductor, diode, etc. I would also recommend adding a 0.1uF MLCC cap right next to your VIN pin to help with transients while driving that internal FET.

Comment: Some time has passed and I created a new PCB layout, which hopefully fixes all problems. I know this questions is basically already closed, but it would mean a lot to me, if you could take a quick look to tell me whether or not it is any better. Only, if you have the time to do it of course! The layout can be found at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Please show the grounding island in a colour - I can't tell how it connects to the rest of the ground without this.

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly do you mean? I thought that the "ground island" refers to the thick copper trace below the IC. (as shown on page 42 of the datasheet). Every ground connection is somehow connected to the island. What exactly do you mean by "how it connects to the rest of the ground"? Since that is visible I'm probably missing your point...

Comment: I see a thick black snaking emptiness and some grey background. I see blue tracks underneath and red tracks on top. To do this properly, the "island" I refer to is underneath on the blue side and, it's an island and not a complex strung out snaking shape that has multiple connections along its length. I can't make head nor tail of your image.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you mean. You said that the island should be underneath on the bottom layer meaning I have to connect all ground connections from mentioned parts with vias to an underlying ground island, right? Also, the entire ground connections should be encapsulated with only a single ground trace going to the rest of the circuit. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct and black should be reserved for the background and not a track colour.

Comment: Alright, I created a new layout. Do you mean something similar to that one? The vias will be encapsulated later on so they won't be connected to any other ground connection.

Comment: I've added a slightly modified version at the bottom of my answer. It improves on yours but yours is now a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your coil core is saturating, you will need a bigger one physically.
If you need less than 2A use 47uH with 10uF caps.